# A kink in my W,A,S,D movement - Javascript Novice

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp, false);

var key = new Set();
function keyDown(k) {
    key.add(k.keyCode);
    if (key.has(83)) {
        player.vy = 1;  
    };
    if (key.has(87)) {
        player.vy = -1;  
    };
    if (key.has(65)) {
        player.vx = -1;
        if (key.has(68)) {
           player.vx = -1; 
        };
    };
    if (key.has(68)) {
        player.vx = 1;
        if (key.has(65)) {
           player.vx = 1; 
        };
    };
};

    function keyUp(k) {
        key.delete(k.keyCode);
        if (k.keyCode === 83) {
            player.vy = 0;  
        };
        if (k.keyCode === 87) {
            player.vy = 0;  
        };
        if (k.keyCode === 65) {
            if (!key.has(68)) {
                player.vx = 0;
            };
        };
        if (k.keyCode === 68) {
            if (!key.has(65)) {
                player.vx = 0;
            };
        };
    };
```

I am trying to create smooth movement when dialing around the W,A,S,D keys. I finally got something that works except one minor glitch. Whenever I am holding D to move right and I press A, the player's movement is not interrupted. That is how I want it to work but when I do the opposite, the movement is interrupted and reversed. If I switch the 2 blocks I pointed out in the code it will reverse the problem, fixing one and breaking the other. I assume its something to do with how its catching the if statements but I don't know. Can someone tell me what the ffffffff is going on?

Comment: Javascript can only detect 1 key at a time. Maybe? Since it is single-threaded, only 1 event would be raised. I guess.

Comment: with the Set() I got it so it can detect multiple.  I was able to convert it to an array and use the first element in the array as a condition and that works for this specific problem but then messes up the other movements and makes it choppy.

Comment: Can you assemble a stack snipped so we all can test it? Please? Since you only provide part of the code, we don't know what `player` is. We can't even see why it is happening. A minimal verifyable example (as little code as possible, and only the one that matters) that shows the bug would help greatly. Till then, it will be simply a bunch of guesses.

Comment: Did you try a switch statement instead?

Comment: The player is just a sprite made with PIXI.js and player.vx and player.vy are just the x and y of the sprite. I don't know why I didn't try a switch. I'll be right back.

Comment: Well that was dumb. The switch worked but for some reason I had to switch the numbers. I don't know how to post the fix.

Comment: @Gyldstrand If you have a solution give it as an answer to this question. Also to have several key events active at a time you can use boolean variables that hold true/false on `keypress` and `keyup`. Then on the movement even check if the boolean is true for movement in a direction.

Comment: I tried that for like 2 hours and couldn't get the same functionality. I want to be able to violently smash the W,A,S,D keys and have smooth movement.